# Display rows with only single record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which I would like to query:

```
create table common.active_pairs
(
    pair                  text,
    exchange_id           integer
);


create table common.exchanges
(                        
    exchange_id         bigint not null
);
```

Table `pair` holds data like `London/Berlin` and etc.

I use this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM common.ACTIVE_PAIRS ap
    INNER JOIN common.exchanges ON exchanges.exchange_id = ap.exchange_id
    // implement logic to check common.ACTIVE_PAIRS.pair to have only one record
WHERE ap.exchange_id = 1
ORDER BY ap.id
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 10
```

How I can select table rows which hold only a single distinct record which is not repeating in other table rows?

Comment: Adding sample data in addition to the table structure you have already showed would help your question.

Comment: Your active_pairs table should have two separate columns for each pair. (Like London in one column, and Berlin in the other. But use id's instead.) And have foreign keys.

Comment: You really should read this; [why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

you want group by and having

```
SELECT ce.exchange_id, cp.exchange_id, pair
FROM common.active_pairs cp
JOIN common.exchanges ce on cp.exchange_id = ce.exchange_id
GROUP BY pair, cp.exchange_id, ce.exchange_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ce.exchange_id
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: can you extend the existing SQL query please?

Comment: there is no point in doing an equal join to a table with one column?

Comment: Actually there are more column but I listed only the pessary ones?

Comment: OK - modified but I haven't tested.(no data set)

Comment: I get error`[42702] ERROR: column reference "exchange_id" is ambiguous Position: 113`

Comment: I've modified to specify cp.exchange_id. Is it OK now?

Comment: I get `[42803] ERROR: column "cp.min_order_exchange_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 8`

Comment: Because there is a GROUP BY every field in the select has to be in the group by. I've specifid the 3 fields that I know instead of *. Will that run?

Comment: I get `Unable to resolve column 'pairs' `

Comment: I've corrected it to pair

Comment: How I can add `WHERE ap.exchange_id = 1`? Maybe it's better to use `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Yes - be free to add where, I think the line before group by. Modify, try test et optimise. Accept my answer if it's working and let me know if not. I have to go and wont be avaliable until later.